# Got ERROR while deleting image from Firebase Storage

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm trying to delete the image from firebase storage. I have an image path and I have checked it. it's totally correct path but delete is not happening. here is the code

```
 final StorageReference riversRef = storageRef.child(Profilepath);
            riversRef.delete().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {



                    ref.child(stateName).child(cityName).child("items").child(mobile_cat)
                            .child(CItemid).setValue(null, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
                            menuadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                            UploadCounterMinus();

                        }
                    });


                    lDialog.dismiss();


                    Toast.makeText(Mobile_items.this.getContext(),"file deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {


                    Toast.makeText(Mobile_items.this.getContext(),"somthing happen, try again!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            });
```

and here is the error

```
05-10 14:13:36.057 12326-19049/localninjabusinessapp.bhupendra.localninjabusiness E/StorageException: {  "error": {    "code": 404,    "message": "Not Found.  Could not delete object"  }}
                                                                                                  java.io.IOException: {  "error": {    "code": 404,    "message": "Not Found.  Could not delete object"  }}
                                                                                                      at bnp.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesc@12529002@12.5.29 (000304-192802242):147)
                                                                                                      at bnp.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesc@12529002@12.5.29 (000304-192802242):119)
                                                                                                      at bnj.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesc@12529002@12.5.29 (000304-192802242):8)
                                                                                                      at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:361)
                                                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzed.zzb(Unknown Source)
                                                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzewv.zzrw(Unknown Source)
                                                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzewz.zze(Unknown Source)
                                                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzewo.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                                                      at com.google.firebase.storage.zza.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                                                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                                                                                                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                                                                                                      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

while I'm using the same code in another activity for deleting pics and its working fine

Comment: It means that you are trying to delete an image that no longer exist at that location or to delete an image that exist in a different location. Have you tried to use real names?

Comment: i have given every image a unique id and i have checked that image  manually in firebase storage that exist at there.  there is no problem in fatching that image from given path but when i try to delete that image its shows error....:(

Answer (score 0):

Actually you cant delete storage item by using object references, you have to take 
image/Video urlReference to delete storage items

Comment: I can't even understand if this is an answer or if you are posting your own problem. In the latter case you should delete your answer and post a new question explaining your problem

Answer (score 0):

You must to review the path, in your case this variable:
Profilepath

This has to be the same than Storage location in Firebase.

If you open chrome you can see storage location below of the image which one you want to delete.

1. To click the image, to see image and after that you can see two options below:

   - File location
   - Other metadata
2. To click the file location.
3. To see storage location.
4. To compare storage location with your variable